# SharePoint navigations is hidden on teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, modern-team-site

We can add SharePoint site as Teams tabs. but some UI are hidden, such navigation bar command bar, even following image show that there is no  save/publish option for event .
is there way to create full SharePoint site experience in teams tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MS Teams will purposefully remove all controls around SharePoint pages such as:

- Left and top navigation.
- "Power Automate" buttons.
- Library title

So far, I conclude that it's impossible to trick Teams to stop ding it.

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint tab in Teams is only designed to show different types of content rather than the entire site experience. You can add a SharePoint page, list or document library as a tab in Microsoft Teams. More information can be found here:

[Add a SharePoint page, list, or document library as a tab in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/office/add-a-sharepoint-page-list-or-document-library-as-a-tab-in-teams-131edef1-455f-4c67-a8ce-efa2ebf25f0b)